# React Native view renders incorrectly after Redux data is updated

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am using `react-redux` and have a simple `Grid` with `react-native-easy-grid`.  It lays out a set of Pegs (circles) correctly.

When I change the settings, for example `numPosInCode` from 6 to 5, the code in the ColourBoard component renders with the wrong geometry.  For example, depending on the simulator the Peg size should be 56 but it gets calculated as 7.55.

The second problem is that only the first column in the `Grid` gets rendered.

These pictures show the initial render, an 8x11 `Grid`, and the incorrect render after the settings have been applied.  It shows a 1x11 `Grid` which should be 7x11 and the Peg size is way too small.

[image: correct initial render][image: incorrect render after the settings change]

Here is my Colourboard code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {Col, Row, Grid} from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import {useBottomTabBarHeight} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Peg from './Peg';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export function ColourBoard() {
  const numPosInCode = useSelector(store => store.gameplay.numPosInCode);
  const numColours = useSelector(store => store.gameplay.numColours);
  const numMoves = useSelector(store => store.gameplay.numMoves);
  const tabBarHeight = useBottomTabBarHeight();
  const usableHeight = height - tabBarHeight - StatusBar.currentHeight;
  console.log(`numPosInCode: ${numPosInCode}`);
  console.log(`numColours: ${numColours}`);
  console.log(`numMoves: ${numMoves}`);
  console.log(`width: ${width}`);
  console.log(`width / (numPosInCode + 2): ${width / (numPosInCode + 2)}`);
  const pegSize = width / (numPosInCode + 2) - 2;
  console.log(`pegSize: ${pegSize}`);
  const top = (usableHeight / (numMoves + 1) - pegSize) / 2;

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.MainContainer,
        {
          top: top,
        },
      ]}>
      <Grid>
        {[...Array(numPosInCode + 2)].map((x, i) => (
          <Col>
            {[...Array(numMoves + 1)].map((x, i) => (
              <Row>
                <Peg pegSize={pegSize} key={i} />
              </Row>
            ))}
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    left: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
  },
});
```

And the entire project is here: http://sendanywhe.re/WEEG3AS7

I am new to React Native but I assume the Colourboard is rendered too quickly, without waiting for the Redux data to update?  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of your numPosInCode. In Javascript, when you add a number to a string or a string to a number, the result is a string. In this case when you did  `numPosInCode + 2`, it becomes 52. What you need to do is to convert the string to a number with the parseInt function.

Heres the fixed code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {Col, Row, Grid} from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import {useBottomTabBarHeight} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Peg from './Peg';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export function ColourBoard() {
  const numPosInCode = parseInt(useSelector(store => store.gameplay.numPosInCode));
  const numColours = useSelector(store => store.gameplay.numColours);
  const numMoves = parseInt(useSelector(store => store.gameplay.numMoves));
  const tabBarHeight = useBottomTabBarHeight();
  const usableHeight = height - tabBarHeight - StatusBar.currentHeight;
  console.log(`numPosInCode: ${numPosInCode}`);
  console.log(`numColours: ${numColours}`);
  console.log(`numMoves: ${numMoves}`);
  console.log(`width: ${width}`);
  console.log(`width / (numPosInCode + 2): ${width / (numPosInCode + 2)}`);
  const pegSize = width / (numPosInCode + 2) - 2;
  console.log(`pegSize: ${pegSize}`);
  const top = (usableHeight / (numMoves + 1) - pegSize) / 2;

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.MainContainer,
        {
          top: top,
        },
      ]}>
      <Grid>
        {[...Array(numPosInCode + 2)].map((x, i) => (
          <Col>
            {[...Array(numMoves + 1)].map((x, i) => (
              <Row>
                <Peg pegSize={pegSize} key={i} />
              </Row>
            ))}
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    left: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
  },
});
```